# Java XML Document loading and then simply printing out is changing the initial document

Tags: java, xml

I am simply loading an XML file into my code, and then printing it out again using a Transformer. This is changing the result. It should be exactly the same as the original. I can't for the life of me figure out what the problem is.

Code that is loading the XML Document:

```
        xmlFile = new File(xmlFilePath);

        DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();

        cxmlDocument = db.parse(xmlFile);

        cxmlElement = cxmlDocument.getDocumentElement();
```

Code that is printing it out to a String:

```
        javax.xml.transform.Transformer transformer = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer();
        transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
        transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.METHOD, "xml");

        StreamResult result = new StreamResult(new StringWriter());
        DOMSource source = new DOMSource(cxmlDocument);

        transformer.transform(source, result);

        String xmlString = result.getWriter().toString();

        return xmlString;
```

Code for saving the document:

```
        FileUtils.writeStringToFile(new File("result.xml"), print());
```

And yes, I'm doing error handling and all that. I just didn't show it here.

The original XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE cXML SYSTEM "http://xml.cXML.org/schemas/cXML/1.2.009/cXML.dtd">
<cXML payloadID="538fc224eb006" timestamp="06/04/2014 08:04:36 pm" signatureVersion="1.0" version="1.2.015" xml:lang="en-US">
   <Header>
      <From>
         <Credential domain="NetworkID">
            <Identity></Identity>
         </Credential>
      </From>
      <To>
         <Credential domain="NetworkId">
            <Identity></Identity>
         </Credential>
      </To>
      <Sender>
         <Credential domain="NetworkID">
            <Identity></Identity>
            <SharedSecret />
         </Credential>
         <UserAgent></UserAgent>
      </Sender>
   </Header>
   <Message Id="cXMLData" deploymentMode="production">
      <PunchOutOrderMessage>
         <PunchOutOrderMessageHeader operationAllowed="create" quoteStatus="final">
            <Total>
               <Money currency="USD">17.96</Money>
            </Total>
         </PunchOutOrderMessageHeader>
         <ItemIn quantity="1">
            <ItemID>
               <SupplierPartID>2889</SupplierPartID>
               <SupplierPartAuxiliaryID>2917</SupplierPartAuxiliaryID>
            </ItemID>
            <ItemDetail>
               <UnitPrice>
                  <Money currency="USD">16.59</Money>
               </UnitPrice>
               <Description xml:lang="en">Men's Port Authority Long Sleeve Easy Care Shirt</Description>
               <UnitOfMeasure>EA</UnitOfMeasure>
            </ItemDetail>
         </ItemIn>
      </PunchOutOrderMessage>
   </Message>
</cXML>
```

The result:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?><cXML payloadID="538e338b3db95" signatureVersion="1.0" timestamp="1970-01-01T12:00:00" version="1.2.015" xml:lang="en-US">
   <Header>
      <From>
         <Credential domain="NetworkID">
            <Identity></Identity>
         </Credential>
      </From>
      <To>
         <Credential domain="NetworkId">
            <Identity></Identity>
         </Credential>
      </To>
      <Sender>
         <Credential domain="NetworkID">
            <Identity></Identity>
            <SharedSecret/>
         </Credential>
         <UserAgent></UserAgent>
      </Sender>
   </Header>
   <Message Id="cXMLData" deploymentMode="production">
      <PunchOutOrderMessage>
         <PunchOutOrderMessageHeader operationAllowed="create" quoteStatus="final">
            <Total>
               <Money currency="USD">17.96</Money>
            </Total>
         </PunchOutOrderMessageHeader>
         <ItemIn quantity="1">
            <ItemID>
               <SupplierPartID>2889</SupplierPartID>
               <SupplierPartAuxiliaryID>2918</SupplierPartAuxiliaryID>
            </ItemID>
            <ItemDetail>
               <UnitPrice>
                  <Money currency="USD">16.59</Money>
               </UnitPrice>
               <Description xml:lang="en">Men's Port Authority Long Sleeve Easy Care Shirt</Description>
               <UnitOfMeasure>EA</UnitOfMeasure>
            </ItemDetail>
         </ItemIn>
      </PunchOutOrderMessage>
   </Message>
</cXML>
```

As you can see these 3 lines:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE cXML SYSTEM "http://xml.cXML.org/schemas/cXML/1.2.009/cXML.dtd">
<cXML payloadID="538fc224eb006" timestamp="06/04/2014 08:04:36 pm" signatureVersion="1.0" version="1.2.015" xml:lang="en-US">
```

Have been changed to:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<cXML payloadID="538e338b3db95" signatureVersion="1.0" timestamp="1970-01-01T12:00:00" version="1.2.015" xml:lang="en-US">
```

The timestamp is different. So is the payload value. And the DOCTYPE line is completely gone. Also the attributes are in a different order.

Also, completely randomly, the only other thing that I can tell changed is the value:

```
<SupplierPartAuxiliaryID>2917</SupplierPartAuxiliaryID>
```

to:

```
<SupplierPartAuxiliaryID>2918</SupplierPartAuxiliaryID>
```

Can anyone help me make sense of this? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some changes you mentioned are predictable. The transformation does not retain `<!DOCTYPE>` declarations. In fact it does not even read it. But you *can* re-generate it with a transformer property:

```
transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.DOCTYPE_SYSTEM, "http://xml.cXML.org/schemas/cXML/1.2.009/cXML.dtd");
```

Attribute order is irrelevant according to the XML specification, so the parser isn't required to preserve it.

The changes in the `payload`, `timestamp` and the `<SupplierPartAuxiliaryID>` shouldn't be happening if you are just reading a file and printing it out. If it's a *generated* file, check if you are not comparing to an outdated version. The timestamp and payload might be generated values. Certainly some other process is changing that data along the way. The parser and the transform wouldn't change the data if you used them as you described.

Comment: Wow. So after looking at it again, I'm an idiot. I was using the wrong source file. But the DOCTYPE_SYSTEM worked perfect for adding that and I also added cxmlDocument.setXmlStandalone(true); before the DomSource is created to remove the standalone="no". That's what I get for working this late.